# Don't have flag dismissal impact flags that have already been dismissed

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, flag-weight

This has been tossed around inside and out between moderators, about how the flag dismissal system works when it comes to old flags. Prior to flag rating, bringing up the old flags helped for context and dismissal wouldn't really do anything. We made assumptions of how it worked in the new system. And, well, the Michaels were right, and I was wrong.

If a dismissed flag is "revived" from someone new flagging the same post, it can be redismissed and alter the flag weight of that user according to the new system. I noticed this after giving Gaming's Community a healthy *<s>+30</s> **+40** bonus* to its flag weight for a single post.

This can also result in someone's flag weight being *cancelled* because someone put a bogus flag on it at a later date.

Can an already-dismissed flag not affect the flag weight when it shows up again?

Comment: I had made the same assumption.  +1 for doing science.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Empirical evidence, collected <s>on a live site with real flags</s> in a controlled enviroment (do not try this at home), suggests this problem has now been fixed!

No flag weight was harmed in the running of the experiments. Your concerns for the safety of arbitrary points is duly noted.

Comment: It's incredibly obvious, isn't it? A foreign experiment is introduced into our precious arbitrary points without the knowledge of the individual. Certainly without any choice. That's the way your hard-core Commie works...I can no longer sit back and allow Communist infiltration, Communist indoctrination, Communist subversion and the international Communist conspiracy to sap and impurify all of our precious arbitrary points. /obligatory_movie_quote

Answer (score 4):

Minor note; we also now "dim" the dismissed flags, for your viewing pleasure.

Comment: I did notice this a few weeks ago, which was a *very* nice feature to see. Thanks, since I haven't said so yet. ♪