# Dismiss flags on the same posts with different validities

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, moderator-abilities

Sometimes a post has both valid flags and invalid flags. As far as I can tell, all the flags on the same post have to be dismissed with the same validity.

The scenario I encountered (on [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2205/what-makes-supermans-alter-ego-different-from-other-superheroes)):

1. A low-quality question is closed.
2. The asker improves the question and flags for reopening.
3. A moderator reopens the question, but doesn't dismiss the flag yet.
4. Someone else flags the question as “off topic”.

Since I agree with the reopening, and I don't consider the question off-topic, I would like to dismiss the first flag as valid and the second flag as invalid. But there's only one set of buttons for both flags.

And just now, two flags on a closed question: one that says “delete it”, the other one that says “reopen it”. The correct course of action is neither (the ideal outcome would be for the question to be edited then reopened). I should provide different feedback to the two flaggers, but I can't.

Unless I've missed something, please allow multiple flags on the same post to be dismissed separately.

Comment: I'm in favour of this. Just to note, even if the first flag had been dismissed, [that doesn't stop the subsequent dismissal from affecting it again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81025/dont-have-flag-dismissal-impact-flags-that-have-already-been-dismissed).

Comment: +1, I had no idea things weren't already done in the manner you're suggesting.

Comment: @Popular To be fair, they originally were, but that was before flag weight and the new dashboard were implemented.

Comment: Does this happen so frequent that it's really necessary?

Comment: @Ivo: something like 10% of the time in my very short mod carrier.

Comment: Much better example: 4x "not an answer", 1x "plz help me!!!". Either you mark one really crappy flag as helpful or you mark 4 perfectly fine flags as invalid.

Comment: Requests to not-auto dismiss custom flags are not *remotely* the same suggestion as this post. Please stop closing those requests as duplicates of this. Yes, they're duplicated, but not of this hardly related request.

Comment: @ThiefMaster The solution (well, not really) to that would be to find a 10K user to cast an "invalid flag" on the bunch.

Comment: @IvoFlipse - it may not happen often, but it certainly is disconcerting when it does.  See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157740/how-is-this-answer-a-valid-answer/157757#comment455771_157757

Comment: Examples: [meta-tag:declined-flags]. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174712/flagged-needed-mod-attention-question-closed-by-mod-but-flag-declined http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174444/why-was-my-flag-for-too-localized-declined-but-the-question-closed-with-the http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174081/flag-please-dont-misuse-the-offensive-flag-on-posts-like-this

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As a stopgap until we get [Tim's new mod interface](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81407/dismiss-flags-on-the-same-posts-with-different-validities/202293#202293) out, you can now dismiss individual flags (or really, same-type flags) on posts.

Just click the flag text on an active flag to bring up the normal dismiss UI - the flag you're handling will be outlined in breathtaking maroon:

[image: showing one flag type out of two highlighted with dismissal dialog open]

Note that while you *can* use this to decline disputed flags (while still marking the "invalid flag" flags as helpful) this is not required and should be reserved for extreme cases only; the default behavior (marking all flags as "disputed") is still the intended outcome for most cases at this time.

Comment: A few notes (realizing this is temporary): Handling this on flags where the post has been expanded causes the entire page to refresh when a flag is handled. If I go 'back', then I can see that flag again, otherwise I lose track of the flag (and can't handle the rest of the flags on that post)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker yeah, I'm ironing out a few bugs right now - just let me know when you see issues.

Answer (score 33):

There is a special moderator-only `/review` interface in the works, that will allow moderators to validate or decline flags individually. As of this writing it's partially complete, it was part of an overhaul of moderator tools that we did about a month and a half ago.

However, we fully intend to finish it <strike>in less than six to eight weeks</strike> soon, dev workload permitting. When done, it will be available in addition to the current moderator dashboard while we refine it, and then hopefully more or less replace it for most things.

This was one of the single most frequent complaints about the system, as the workflow basically forced moderators to validate bogus flags in an effort to not penalize valid ones - it was a major feature upgrade in what we have brewing.

Comment: @Tim will the code change affect the 10K tools as well? See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208869/152859) for example.

Comment: Will the revamp allow [adding custom messages when marking a flag as helpful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160338/allow-moderators-to-reply-to-a-flag) as well?