# Posts deleted by the author should not automatically mark a custom flag as helpful

Tags: feature-request, flags, deleted-posts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dismiss flags on the same posts with different validities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81407/dismiss-flags-on-the-same-posts-with-different-validities)
>   [Don't automatically dismiss custom flags (containing a comment from a user)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142839/dont-automatically-dismiss-custom-flags-containing-a-comment-from-a-user)

On *Drupal Answers*, there have been an answer for [Is Drupal appropriate for what I want to do?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44746/is-drupal-appropriate-for-what-i-want-to-do) that has been flagged with a custom reason, and then deleted by its author. As result, the flags were automatically handled, and none of the moderators were probably able to see the custom flag.

[image: screenshot]

Automatically handling flags such as "very low quality," or "not an answer," makes sense, as once the post has been deleted, there is nothing left for the moderators (which eventually would delete the flagged posts).
There are other flags that are about the post, and the user who posted it: A spam flag is about the post, but it also about the user who can be a potential spammer. The same can be said about a custom flag: There are cases where a user needs to flag another user, and the suggested action is generally to flag a post written by that user.

As the custom flag could be about the user, it is probably better not to automatically handle them, or at least notify the moderators in some way.

If doing this for every custom flag raised against a post deleted by its author is not convenient, it should at least be considered for those posts with other flags, including comment flags. In this case, there were three "rude/offensive" flags for three different comments.

Comment: custom flags shouldn't *ever* be auto-marked as helpful...in fact I think a mod deletion doesn't remove the flag. I have no idea why a self-delete clears them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10930859/revisions is the example where this was a problem I remember best.

Comment: @jonsca This is quite different, as it is not about flags dismissed by the moderators, but automatically dismissed  flags. The other question is about moderators being able to dismiss single flags, instead of dismissing all the flags raised for a post. In my case, I was not even able to see the flag because it was automatically dismissed when the author of the answer deleted it, not because it was voted for deleting from 3 10K users. This is another difference.

Comment: @kiamlaluno The question that Flexo marked as a duplicate was closed as a duplicate of that post that I chose, though.  I would agree that your situation is slightly different, but I think at its root, the problem is the same.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I was always under the impression it's a bad habit to close as a dupe of an already closed as duplicate question, but maybe that's my own misinterpretation of it.

Comment: @jonsca it's really not remotely the same. Custom flags shouldn't be auto-dismissed. Auto-dismissal is different from manually selecting different validity per flag. At best manually selecting validities is a half-assed workaround, not a solution, to this problem.

Comment: @BenBrocka Then the other question that Flexo has chosen is not a duplicate of the one I cited.  I was merely trying to go back through the chain rather than create another link.

Comment: @jonsca Effectively, separately dismissing different flags is different from automatically dismissing custom flags. I voted to reopen that question.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Good deal, I have just done the same.

Comment: I am going to vote to close this question. As long as Stack Exchange doesn't answer about that other question, I consider mine a duplicate. If Stack Exchange replies saying that automatically dismissing any flag for a post is fine, then this can considered an alternative request not to dismiss custom flags when the author of the post deletes her/his own post.