# Mod flag for plagiarism

Tags: support, flags, plagiarism

If I raise a moderator flag pointing out blatant plagiarism, and the OP deletes the post (perhaps because of downvotes, or because someone points out the plagiarism), what happens? Does a moderator still see the flag and take any necessary action on the account (for instance, if it's not the first time the account has been used to plagiarize)?

Comment: Yes, moderator flags are never cleared automatically. Your flag will still sit in the mod-queue.

Comment: Thanks @rene, that's good to hear. Do you have a reference for it? (Not that I don't believe you, you're very active on meta so it wouldn't surprise me if you've run across this info and remembered it, even if you can't immediately point to where.)

Comment: Hmm, I'm pretty sure I've asked this before on SOCVR but can't find it. Here on MSE this comes closest: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175420/158100

Answer (score 3):

Custom flags are not deleted on closure/deletion:

> Currently, when users are putting a custom flag on a post, there is a chance that this flag will be dismissed before a moderator could see it.

...

> This has been [fixed for years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175751), the question just never got updated. Custom flags can never be dismissed by non-moderator action. – [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson)

Source [Don't automatically dismiss custom flags (containing a comment from a user) - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142839/dont-automatically-dismiss-custom-flags-containing-a-comment-from-a-user) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: Thanks! I've voted to close my question as a duplicate of that one.