# Is there a way to respond to a declined flag verdict?

Tags: support, review, flags, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I just flagged an answer that was, well, not an answer. Checking my flagging history, this was declined in error, or possibly due to a bug in the system - see screenshot:

[image]

Is there anyway to politely tell the mod that I did correctly flag this?

**EDIT-** Seeing as this is a limitation to the mod tools, Wouldn't it be easier for the mod to simply select the correct course of action themselves, and the users that flagged in that same manner be awarded the helpful flag?

Comment: No, there's not, but in this specific case this will be relevant to your interests: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158921/not-an-answer-flag-declined-with-this-is-not-spam-use-not-an-answer-for-this.

Comment: Lol, the same question being flagged and declined.

Comment: @nhahtdh Lol, it is to.

Comment: +1, I actually had case when mod's response was *offensive*.  I'd prefer to settle it down rather than bury it deep inside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot answer back to a declined flag. Moderators can give you a reason for declining your flag, but you cannot reply back.

If you want to understand why your flag was declined, what the moderator meant, or why what the moderator said applies to your case, then you can ask on the meta site for the site where you flagged a post.

Comment: What if I just want to defend against offensive mod?  In such case, asking in meta feels like whistle-blowing, whereas it's much more fair to try to settle it down first (not necessarily PM, a facility like comments would be OK).

Comment: If a moderator is being really offensive, click on the "contact us" link you find on the footer of that Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Good point, I completely forgot about that link.  However, contacting SE directly is even more "whistle-blowing" than asking on meta.  In my case, they were not *that* offensive.