# Is it allowed to repost a question a day after it has been removed

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Not long ago, I had my attempts to clarify a question were met with antagonising comments. I nevertheless worked to find an answer (yup, I know, shouldn't have). By the time I got back to type it in, the question had been deleted. Possibly because of the authors' antagonising comments. As a fiddle had been provided, I updated the fiddle with my answer. There didn't appear to be any way to notify the person.

The next day, the same question was reposted. So far as I could tell, an exact copy and paste. To avoid pointless confrontation, I flagged the post but there didn't seem to be any type of follow up (no notification, no way to know if anybody checked it out). I tried to address that with the author and all I got for it was more antagonising comments. Some getting into the abusive zone.

The question is: [How do I create a column chart with negative values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620242/how-do-i-create-a-column-chart-with-negative-values/15621166?noredirect=1#comment22476295_15621166)

Where can I find the rules on question reposting? What can I expect to happen when I flag a post?

Comment: In your [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/421512/widged) there should be a count of your helpful flags (after profile views). The number is a link, click it and you'll see the responses to all your flags (more recent first).

Comment: So the original question was deleted by the OP, and then re-asked in a somewhat different way? (He states: *"This question was slightly different than the one I removed.*") I don't really see a problem with that.

Comment: Exact copy and paste as far as I could tell.

Comment: For those (with 10k+) who are curious; the original was nearly a perfect copy, with very slight wording differences: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605220/d3-chart-with-negative-values

Comment: @Yannis thanks for the tip. Just found it. I have "declined" but not other information

Comment: @Bart I don't think an _exact_ copy paste would be possible, the system barks at you when you try to repost exactly the same question (even if the first one is deleted). That said, it's pretty easy to change a couple of words for the new question to go through.

Comment: @widged Oh; yes, it does seem like that flag was declined! I'll edit my answer to explain...

Comment: @Yannis Yeah, admittedly I went off the comment made by the OP of that question.

Comment: @widged A sidenote: Deleted questions count towards an automatic question ban. If the OP (or anyone else) makes a habit of deleting and re-posting their questions, the system will eventually catch up and confront them with an ugly little message that in no uncertain terms says: "Sorry, but enough is enough". It's not a problem if they do it once or twice, but if there's a repeating pattern then it will be dealt with automagically.

Comment: @Andrew Barber Thanks.

Comment: To whoever did it, thanks for cleaning up the comments on the question page.

Answer (score 8):

I handled the flag on the duplicate. <strike>I marked it as helpful because it brought the issue to our attention using an 'Other' flag type.</strike> **EDIT:** One flag was declined. Someone had placed an 'offensive/spam' flag on it, and I declined that flag, if I recall correctly. But earlier, an Other' flag had been placed, and Will marked that one Helpful. I did not close or delete the question because the original had already been duplicated, and work had been put into the new one.

Normally no; we don't want people to post multiple copies of the same question, and we would prefer people edit and undelete, even if they do delete the original. Also, we don't like people being rude. I am cleaning up comments, now, and will do anything else that seems appropriate in the situation which occurred.

One bit of advice, which you seem to have arrived at yourself, in a way; If someone is being rude to you, don't bother bending over backwards to find solutions for them, unless you really want to take more abuse. Flag the rudeness for us, specifically, and move on.

Comment: [Dismiss flags on the same posts with different validities](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81407/dismiss-flags-on-the-same-posts-with-different-validities) (just saying ;)

Comment: @Yannis Yup! But also, check out the question I put a bounty on; I keep forgetting about that, too! Also, in this case, the 'Other' flag had already been handled (and accepted), so it doesn't apply here. Pffft!

Comment: @Andrew Barber♦ Thanks for the edits, that's perfect.

Comment: @AndrewBarber The one marked as declined in my flag list is the one that signal the copy/paste issue. Accepted/declined status doesn't matter much. Current actions do the tricks. However, I didn't get to read it before today... Possible to have a link to the flag page make it to my inbox or the notification box when flag looked into? Paradoxically, the comments from the author (unpleasant ones) showed after the question had been deleted. Possible for these not to show in my box after a post has been deleted? Should I make another meta request for that?

Comment: @widged You should post separate feature requests for both issues. I think the first one (a better way to get notified of flag responses) has been asked before, so search a bit before you post it.

Comment: @AndrewBarber for me to be able to check the answer as accepted. "Where can I find the rules on question reposting?".

Comment: @AndrewBarber Just found out that it hadn't been declined. Initially, I read it as declined being a heading for the next paragraph (the text that flagged the question repost issue). Got it. It's not. Two separate actions. My bad. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @widged No need to apologize there; I was also a bit confused when looking at it at first!