# Understanding why this not an answer flag was declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, not-an-answer, specific-answer

I was reviewing the list of flagged posts, and came across one that was marked as "Not an Answer". The full response was:

> [i have same problem, pls answer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16527291/104223)

I agreed with the existing flag, so I too marked it as "Not an Answer".  However it was declined, for the following reason:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical
>   inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

From my perspective, it clearly was not an answer. Am I missing something or misusing that flag perhaps?

(I can see how some cases might be bit subjective, so I am not interested in blaming or starting a debate. I would just like to understand whether I am using that flag correctly and if not - how it *should* be used.

Comment: If other people flagged it with flags that were grossly inappropriate (spam, for instance), then your flag was probably declined together with those. Individual flags cannot be moderated individually - they all have to be taken care of at once.

Comment: @J.Steen - Ah, I was not aware that all flags were handled at once. That could well be the answer to my question .. and would certainly make a lot more sense ;-) Unfortunately .. this probably *is* a duplicate question. I did search, but must have used the wrong phrase, because none of the results gave that answer.

Comment: @J.Steen I couldn't find an exact duplicate [with a very lazy, cursory search](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=flag+declined). But it probably does exist.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Same here. I think there are several answers, and only a few of the duplicates include *all* of the possibilities. =)

Comment: @Leigh Yeah. Seems like, with all the possibilities, it's hard to find that perfect duplicate. ;)

Comment: @J.Steen - Haha, I got lost in a mire of subjective debates on what constitutes "not an answer" ;) It was probably in the next link I did *not* click on. (Thanks for your help, btw. Much appreciated!)

Comment: It's called "an accident."  Reflagging was all that was necessary.

Comment: see: [Dismiss flags on the same posts with different validities](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81407/dismiss-flags-on-the-same-posts-with-different-validities) "Sometimes a post has both valid flags and invalid flags. ...please allow multiple flags on the same post to be dismissed separately. "

Comment: @Won't - Reflagged by whom? I could be wrong, but I was under the impression I could not flag the same post twice (for the same thing). *(Edit)* A quick search turned up conflicting answers in the archives. But I will keep that in mind if it happens again in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, your flag was correct, but the flag could have been declined either because of what J. Steen stated (someone flagged it with the wrong flag, in which case all flags get declined together), or maybe the moderator (who is a human, allegedly) simply made a mistake when marking the flag. I notice the answer *was* deleted, but unlike the others on that page, it does not say by who.

Comment: Yes, I noticed the deleted by was missing too and wondered if it might have something to do with it. But I suspect what you and @J.Steens suggested is the cause: a bad flag by someone else. Thanks guys!

Comment: If it says only "deleted", I assume it means "from the VLQ queue".