# Only dismiss flags of the same type when one is declined as not a valid flag

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, declined-flags

Highly related: [Dismiss flags on the same posts with different validities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81407/dismiss-flags-on-the-same-posts-with-different-validities)

Similar to the above but narrower in scope, only dismiss other flags on a post if they are of the same type being dismissed.

This would solve basically all of the problems seen currently on meta concerning invalid flag dismissal including the scenario envisioned in [in this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81407/dismiss-flags-on-the-same-posts-with-different-validities#comment397176_81407).

Example scenario with new feature: 4 people mark a question as `not a real question` and one person marks it as `spam`, the spam gets dismissed while the 4 valid `not a real question` can be marked helpful.

Under the current system if the `spam` flag was dismissed then the 4 valid `not a real question` flags would also get dismissed. Which can be very frustrating when the question is then closed minutes later as `not a real question`!

Good example of this being useful would be if there are multiple `localized` flags when in reality the question is `not constructive` or `not a real question` or `off topic`. You could dismiss one localized flag - thereby dismissing **all** the `localized` flags - without dismissing the other valid flags.

As I see it this would only be changing the current functionality a tiny little bit, instead of changing the whole flow to make it so that each individual flag had to be accepted or declined. (which is what I understand the other question to be about).

Comment: The flagging revamp is coming out in a couple weeks, so this will be moot shortly.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure manually validating individual flags is one of the new features so this won't be needed/will be part of what happens.

Comment: @BenBrocka oh, can you post where that I can find out all the new features? I'm on meta pretty much every day and I hadn't seen that, hence the question.

Comment: @ryan it's been mentioned in the Teacher's Lounge many times, but Anna just closed this as a dupe of the post they marked "status planned". So roughly the requested feature there should make it into the flag overhaul

Comment: @BenBrocka ah yea... well glad there was some sort of update it's rare that a 2 year old thread gets the "status planned" tag.