# Declined NAA flag - why?

Tags: support, declined-flags, specific-answer

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19976426/203657) looks very much as not-an-answer to me but was declined (no evidence). On the bright side: it was at least deleted :-)

Screenshot so <10K can judge as well:

> [image]

Any idea as to why my flag was declined?

Comment: Probably moderator's innocent mistake. This is absolutely not an answer.

Comment: Could also be a moderator declining a spam flag and with it all other flags, as they can't be declined individually.

Comment: Probably someone flagged as offensive or spam, and they didn't want to  mark that as "helpful". If someone was glancing over and looked at "wine bottles" one might have thought it was spam.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy good point, the contents might hint spam (though no link) so someone might have flagged as such. But on a mod can confirm that. :)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy ahhh, yeah, suspected spam could well be, thanks

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd good idea to add a screenshot to allow everybody reading it - thanks :-)

Comment: @kleopatra Moderators being able to individually dismiss flags (so yours helpful and the spam one unhelpful) is [currently being worked on](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81407/dismiss-flags-on-the-same-posts-with-different-validities) so this won't remain a problem for long

Comment: @RichardTingle thanks for the info, will indeed be helpful :-)

Comment: I will admit that in my haze of flagging activity this morning I incorrectly hit offensive on that answer - of course I meant NAA. My flag was obviously declined because it was not offensive...this was my mistake. _hangs head in shame_

Comment: @bluefeet not a big problem, I just was in the mood to get some ensurance :-) BTW, after stinky change of sequence (unergonomically having the most frequent reason _not_ at the top) it got really easy to hit spam accidentablly ... been there.

Comment: @kleopatra Yeah, it just sucks when you get declined flags.  As soon as I saw your post, I checked my flags and thought _what the heck did I do?_ I'm not exactly sure how I incorrectly flagged it, I guess I was overly anxious to clear out the flag queue this morning.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Because certain things sort of stink, namely some of our moderator tools.

Your flag was valid, however a SPAM flag on the same post needed to be declined. Currently, we can't decline flags selectively (a new moderator interface in the works permits this, but it's a little while out).

Since [validated quality related flags are used for review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160754/why-are-the-moderators-being-so-strict-with-quality-related-flags-recently/160755#160755), I'm really sorry, but I had to invalidate that SPAM flag, which also now feeds our spam mitigation system as well. I couldn't validate it.

You didn't do anything wrong, just a quirk. We might be bolting some work-around scripts in place as a stop-gap until the new tools are ready for use.