# How to disagree with one flag but agree with another

Tags: discussion, flags, 10k-tools

While visiting the flags I just noticed that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059786/facebook-video-embedding-status-is-enabled-but-it-doesnt-display/20188719#20188719) answer has two flags:

1. very low quality
2. not an answer

I disagree that it is "not an answer", but I agree that this might be of "very low quality". I can't simply select "it has invalid flags" as that means I disagree with both flags. What should I do in this case? Use "other" option?

Comment: Instead of worrying about a user gaining/losing a helpful flag, you should take the necessary action based on your opinion about the post itself.

Comment: Currently even diamond mods can't do that; as you can see in the linked post there's a plan to fix that though only for mods.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, thanks. So in such cases(after the implementation is done) I will flag with the one that I agree, but won't do anything with the one that I disagree, right?

Comment: @taskinoor not sure, worth asking. As far as I understand it will only affect diamond moderators but I'll ask Tim.