# Improve description of offensive flag

Tags: feature-request, flags, offensive

A while ago, I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20612203/1):

> These answers are ALL wrong! Getting to the point, the CORRECT answer is The Break Statement.

I thought that "a reasonable person" would deem this answer "inappropriate for respectful discourse," so I flagged it as offensive. Later, I saw:

> flagged as `offensive` declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

I [brought this up at The Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/discussion-about-the-description-for-the-offensive-flag), and got responses like this:

> It's not really offensive though, is it?

> It's crappy answer, no doubt, but not offensive.

So in my opinion it does fit the description for the offensive flag, but *does not* deserve to be flagged as offensive. I now agree that it did not deserve to be deleted, but the fact remains that I flagged it because I had thought it fit the description (and still do). Offensive is a semi-relative term, so I thought that in this case offensive was defined by the description:

> This answer contains content that a reasonable person would deem inappropriate for respectful discourse.

I think the description for the offensive flag should be changed to something else that does not include answers like the example above.

**I'm not trying to make this a discussion about that particular answer and my subsequent flag. I'm trying to say that there are people that may flag a post because they think fits the description, even though the post shouldn't be deleted. Not everyone is a reasonable person.**

Comment: I'm a reasonable person (I think) and I don't find it all that inappropriate.  Sure, it could have been more constructively phrased, but certainly not in the realm of offensive.

Comment: This is hardly offensive. You might say it is a little bit direct but that's all there is to it. I would never consider this offensive.

Comment: I'm deeply offended that @psubsee considers himself reasonable.

Comment: @Shog9 I do my best to be as deeply offensive as possible, but only to unreasonable people, so hopefully no one is flagging my comment as offensive.

Comment: <sarcasm>You guys are all WRONG! It is DEFINITELY inappropriate for respectful discourse.</sarcasm>

Comment: It's an answer.  You have edit privileges, right?  Edit it to change the wording.  How about "In my opinion, the correct answer is the break statement."  No caps, no strong opinion, maintains the message, couldn't possibly offend anyone, and no flag needed.  In fact, someone has already made a similar change.

Comment: @Charles I know that (now), but that has no relation to whether the answer fits the flag description.

Comment: Why is this getting so many downvotes? Disagreement with the proposed change? I sure hope it's not a "that's not offensive" downvote, because that is not the point of the question it seems. And the wording of the flag is indeed rather broad, though I'm not so sure it needs changing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here...

1. I'm not that convinced that "reasonable people" are all that offended by that answer. It got two "offensive" flags, which is two flags more than *most* answers get, but far less than the 6 needed for automatic removal. Lots of people who *could've* flagged that answer visited the question and didn't flag it, so either there's a majority of unreasonable folks around here or it's just not that big of a deal.
2. There was a mixture of "offensive" and "not an answer" flags on the post at the time your flag was handled. Currently, it's not possible to dismiss different types of flags with different messages, so you got the standard "yes it is an answer just a bad one" response along with everyone else. [A fix for this *is* being worked on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81407/dismiss-flags-on-the-same-posts-with-different-validities), but... Even if it already existed, I wouldn't be too confident of a different response here given #1.

Regardless, if it offended *you* then you were right to flag it - that's what the flag is for. That it was dismissed indicates only that this wasn't the prevailing opinion: part of working as a member of a larger community is being willing to accept when your feelings and ideas aren't acceptable to the group.

Comment: Okay, a reasonable person does not think it's _offensive_. However, they may still think it is _inappropriate for respectful discourse_, or an _unreasonable_ person may think that a reasonable person may think it's inappropriate.

Comment: Indeed they might! But, they didn't. So it goes...

Answer (score 5):

I suggest:

> This answer contains content that a reasonable person would deem highly inappropriate for respectful discourse.

Adding "highly" should make the difference. :)