# Tool/Library recommendation flag

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383493/self-hosted-node-js-error-tracking

I flagged this post as off-topic under the "Recommending a tool, library, or favourite off-site resource" reason and it was declined.

I'm usually pretty spot on with flagging, but on the other couple of declined flags I have it's been pretty clear to me why they were declined. I don't see it with this one though, can anyone help explain why its on-topic?

Comment: The person who handled your flag probably declined it by mistake. It looks correct to me.

Comment: Or there were other flags on the post that needed to be declined, and yours got caught in the crossfire.

Comment: Don't worry, the question is closed now.

Comment: This is an issue that moderators can only decline all flags or approve all flags, so if there was (for example) a spam flag on the post they would have to decline them all. [This is set to change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81407/dismiss-flags-on-the-same-posts-with-different-validities) so hopefully won't be a problem for too much longer

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thanks for that information.

Comment: .@Mat's comment is correct.