# Links to other posts broken on some posts' flags in the moderator queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, moderator-tools

When viewing the moderator queue, posts which have other posts linked below them (such as those flagged as 'Duplicate Answers' or 'Multiple questions closed') have broken anchors;

It looks like some tag has not been closed properly. The links to the posts below will work if you click them, but the whole lot of them will highlight (underline) together when hovering over any of them, and you'll also get the popup for the "No action needed" button when you middle-click to open in a new tab.

[image]

Comment: It's because they're putting a block-level element inside an inline element. That's just how it renders when you do that. I brought this up when they were going through the "flag text allows HTML to be rendered" fiasco but they didn't seem worried about it. Just to clarify: there's no broken HTML or missing text - this could probably be fixed pretty easily by making the element with the yellow background an inline block or something.

Comment: But it seemed to work ok until just recently, @animuson

Comment: It's been like that for ages. ;P

Comment: Hmmm... I don't think my explanation was good, and my screen shot sucks, too. Heh... the problem I mean here only started a short while ago. I'll try again later ;) @animuson

Comment: Yeah, another of my bugs - I hate that dashboard.

Comment: How's the revamp going @Jarrod?

Comment: @BoltClock Shog and Tim will be discussing a plan with meta soon, and it's all I'm going to be working on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by my implementation of ["Dismiss flags on the same posts with different validities"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225779/3) - I was naively making any flag text clickable, which is bad when there's a list of post anchors inside said flag text.

Next build will move the post list outside the "click to dismiss" area.

Comment: Awesome sauce!!