# Declined flag, but post was deleted

Tags: discussion, flags

I flagged [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586515/match-only-a-or-b-case-insensitive/22476694#22476694) as "Not an answer" but my flag was declined:

[image]

I want to improve my flags by understanding what posts should I flag and what kind of flag should I arise, so I entered the question to see it again. I saw that it was deleted by a moderator and it's totally not an answer.

What could be the reason for declining my flag? That's not the first time my flag was declined but the post was deleted by a moderator after that.

Comment: Could have been a mis-click, or there were other flags on that post that were wrong and had to be declined (like 'spam', that's not spam, it's not trying to sell anything).

Comment: @Martijn But, but, we can decline flags individually now.

Comment: @animuson: I was wondering about that; that'd leave the 'mis-click' option. So why *was* that flag declined then?

Comment: @animuson Wait, what? How do we decline individual flags?

Comment: Maybe thought it was easier? Aside from NAA flags, there were also spam, offensive, and VLQ flags. Or possibly didn't know you can dismiss them individually, like Bill here.

Comment: @Bill Click the actual flag reason rather than a button. It'll popup the dialog and dismiss only that flag.

Comment: @animuson Nice! I got so used to processing flags a certain way, I didn't even notice when that change went it.  :)

Comment: I've missed that change too :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was the moderator who processed the flag.  The post had 2 spam flags plus several not an answer flags on it.  While the post is utter nonsense, it is not spam so those flags were declined.

We recently were given the [ability to handle flags separately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81407/dismiss-flags-on-the-same-posts-with-different-validities) which would allow us to decline the spam and mark the Not an Answer flags as helpful.  I'm not sure if I tried to decline the spam flag and it declined everything since it was a new process at that point.

Obviously, it was a mis-click during the handling of the flag.  This is why it still wound up deleted.