# Formatting in flags

Tags: support, flags, markdown

Is it possible to use Markdown formatting in flag messages, in the box titled "other (needs ♦ moderator attention)". For example, if I attempt to use a [markdown link](https://stackoverflow.com/) or *italics*, will the moderator handling the flag see the intended formatting, or see the markup itself?

Comment: Yes it supports basic markdown and links are working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes basic markdown is supported, here's my proof:

> [image]

Comment: Note that links are a bit tricky to follow because the entire body of a flag is itself a link (to allow [handling flags individually](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81407/dismiss-flags-on-the-same-posts-with-different-validities)).

Comment: @mmyers oh didn't know that... but are they still useable?

Comment: Right click works fine. Left click makes the flag dismissal dialog flash before navigation. Middle click (which is what I usually do elsewhere) works but also brings the flag dismissal dialog up.

Comment: @mmyers doesn't sound nice, maybe start a bug report? :)