# Can we handle flags on the same comment separately?

Tags: feature-request, comments, flags, moderator-tools

Can we have the ability to handle flags on the same  comment separately?

Sometimes one flag will be helpful and another will not be and they both will either be declined or marked helpful.

Related:

[Dismiss flags on the same posts with different validities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81407/dismiss-flags-on-the-same-posts-with-different-validities)

Comment: You mean the trick described in the linked post only works for post flags? (Ask Different doesn't see that much comment flags, so I can't test it ...)

Comment: @Glorfinde Yes. We have hundreds every day. (on SO not Pets!)

Comment: *Goes ranting in comments on Pets.se* ...

Comment: Why is that important on comments? Only to get a specific user sooner flag banned?

Comment: @rene comment flags don't lead to flag bans, but multiple unintendedly validated 'unfriendly' flags could accumulate and give the false impression a certain user regularly posts unfriendly comments.

Comment: @Glorfindel ah, that is bad, yes. +1 from me then. Go mods!

Comment: I am haaaalf certain I have asked this before in teams

Comment: @rene some people flag innocuous, but no longer needed comments as harassment and bigotry. Which someone else may flag as no longer needed. It would be good to be able to handle those flags separately. I've been onto Shog to enable comment flag bans for people who flag badly frequently. If that ever does happen this will also help then, 
Yeh the rude/unkind flags trip and auto flag for mods to investigate the account.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek are the team feature requests ever actioned?

Comment: No, but I think it's there, just with terrible ui