# Should I continue flagging for this kind of problem?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting, declined-flags

Generally I flag for the users who do/get false serial upvoting. Since now I have found many users getting upvoting. Generally I do flag for a moderator attention for this kind of actions. I found users doing upvoting in lots of way. I detect these kind of voting fraud just by looking at their reputation tab. I do not use any kind of script for this.

But since last 3-4 days my such flags getting declined by moderators. When I had conversion with moderators regarding these declined reason, they said that "We(Moderator) investigate vote fraud in different way than I do. we look at different things and consecutive votes are not that visible from there."

Have a look at to my recent declined flag's history.

> [image]

Now I am 100% sure that these were false/serial upvoting fraud, and after looking at reputation tab of these user's, moderators were also agree with me.

So the situation is Moderators are right in their decision and I am also right at my flags. So my question is should i continue to flag for these kind of voting fraud ?

Comment: How do you know by looking at a user's reputation tab? Users often get multiple votes in a short time. *That doesn't mean they're from the same person.*

Comment: @EliahKagan, Yes agree with you, but it is like un-common if user is getting serial vote up for more than one question & answer in short time then it is 100% Serial Voting. I am not talking about vote on one particular post. Have a look at this http://i.stack.imgur.com/mqv9a.png don't you think it is serial upvote ?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that's serial upvoting. Of course, it's possible, but most of the time that's *not* serial upvoting. I've seen that many upvotes and more, on many people's profiles, where vote fraud was not the cause. Stack Overflow is big--even by chance, some people will have a lot of their posts upvoted in a short time, some of the time. Furthermore, users who promote their posts by sharing links to them (or have multiple posts shared by others) can get lots of quick reputation without any individual person voting more than once.

Comment: To my knowledge, serial upvoting is generally detected as suspicious along with serial downvoting, and is typically reverted.

Comment: TBH, I think it ***is*** a serial vote up. But, it might not have been significant enough to where it becomes actionable.

Comment: @EliahKagan, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137940/173001 Please , Read the question & answer properly

Comment: FWIW: I spot-checked a few of these declined flags, and while you *might* be onto something I can't be certain - there's just not enough data. The moderators handling these flags don't see quite everything I do, and you see far less than they do. Many of your flags do end up pointing to much larger problems, but in some cases it's *just* superficially suspicious - nothing more.

Comment: @Lucifer [That](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mqv9a.png) doesn't show the same thing as [that other question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137940/173001), which you had never asked me to look at before. Your wording suggests you mean to say that I was looking at something inadequately before, but if that is what you mean, you'll have to explain. I stand by what I said. [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mqv9a.png) *could* be serial upvoting, but it doesn't look like it to me. In particular, it looks much *less* like serial upvoting than [that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137940/173001).

Comment: @EliahKagan, both are different cases but votting pattern is same, that's what i am saying, and if you see the answer, again moderator is agree with me that it is false voting case, but again my flag was declined in that case.

Comment: @Lucifer What do you mean when you say the pattern is the same? About twice the reputation is conferred [there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137940/173001) than [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mqv9a.png). To look like serial upvoting, there should be a large volume of votes that remain even after you remove those that you would expect might occur normally. To me, the patterns in your two examples seem entirely different. Moderators or  SE employees with access to additional tools may of course be able to provide a more informed evaluation of any particular situation.

Comment: @EliahKagan, From my past 1 year's experience i don't require a large volume for to detect a serial voting. I can detect serial voting even for small cases like 2-3 vote ups ( with 100% surity ). I will stop my conversion here. Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you've contributed substantially to moderation efforts. (Which is awesome--thanks!) But as efforts to encourage prolific (non-fraudulent) voting have made headway, there are more votes, and profiles are expected to show more votes. Past performance doesn't guarantee future results, and the changing voting landscape suggests that assuming continued near-100% accuracy is imprudent. As Tim Post said (below) "things are different enough that you'll end up flagging benign patterns more often than not." (I understand you don't wish to reply and that silence doesn't imply agreement.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the past, you have been *extremely* good at noticing irregular voting patterns when you happened to stumble upon them. In fact, I remember noting to one of the other moderators last year that I wasn't quite sure how you did it without the aid of the tools moderators have to confirm this sort of thing.

Since then, our volume has increased, changes have been made to our review system, changes have been made to how the system is explained to new users and all of this sums up to more voting happening on the site which is *good*.

What I recommend you do is *not* actively try to seek out these patterns in the future like you have in the past. If you see a really badly written post that received an abnormal amount of votes, you should flag it for attention. It might be sockpuppets at play or even possibly someone sleep-reviewing (though, audits tend to catch these cases pretty quickly). Remember, we also have things that run daily to reverse this kind of thing which have also been improved.

Just don't actively seek it out like you once did, things are different enough that you'll end up flagging benign patterns more often than not. Unless it's very blatant, this sort of thing is just very difficult to detect accurately without the tools that moderators have.

Comment: I agree, the new users become quite smart, they do not do serial upvoting but rather than do voting in small small steps like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/Sldb3.png and some are even more smarter than this.

Comment: When you begin examining these small steps as you put, it becomes virtually impossible to distinguish malice from benign behavior without more supporting data. When once you would flag when you thought 'Moderators need to see this', a better criteria might be 'How in the *heck* did the moderators miss this?'. That said, if you want to watch these smaller patterns over time and then report when you see them consistently repeat, you'd probably be accurate more often than not, or at least accurate enough to justify  having the mods take a look. Don't be discouraged, just need more data.