# Tools -> Flags is showing items that are voted on to close as flags; shows incorrect options

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, flags, 10k-tools

On the flags tab of the 10k tools, items that are voted on to close are shown, along with the reasons the items are being voted on to close, and a button to *flag* the post:

[image: Flag button when on Tools - flags]

These items are appearing in the section when people vote to close.  When I click on the flag button, I get the following:

[image: Flag dialog]

This is *not* what I expect when I click the flag button.  Perhaps it is correct that a flag dialog comes up when a "flag" button is clicked, but it seems to me that having an item that has close votes showing up on the flags page allowing people to *flag* it for moderator attention is a little strange.

I think this point is especially important because this can ultimately affect flag weight negatively; a moderator might be prone to dismiss a flag (or whatever they do to remove it and have a negative impact on flag weight) if they see that a question is going to be handled naturally by the community.

Placing the ability to flag on these items gives 10K+ rep users the impression that items which are on their way to being closed should be flagged instead, which is incorrect.

Comment: Also, there's a message on the right (which I haven't seen before): *Posts flagged for moderator attention are in strict confidence.*  Are we *really* supposed to be seeing this page in this way?  Seems like a bug and it's showing us at least a hybrid full-moderator view.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93623/feedback-on-tools-flagged-changes

Comment: @Shog9: [Added answer there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93623/feedback-on-tools-flagged-changes/93666#93666) linking back to this specific issue.

Comment: confirmed this, will add a close button.

Comment: @waffles: I'd suggest that you be given one or the other, not both (or *maybe*, depending on what exactly is going on (is it flagged, voted on to close, or *both*?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a close button with the number of close votes for questions.

I kept the flag option for a few reasons:

1. The flag may be invalid, if so please let us know by choosing the "invalid flag" option.
2. The post may need mod attention, it makes it easy to add a message.

Keep in mind, if you vote to close the post will no longer show up on your list.

Comment: For reference, the close button appears even on posts that are already closed.  Clicking it leads to a box that says as much...but the post is still in my list.

Comment: aha ... another bug

Comment: I have verified that the close dialog is there.  Not sure if I should accept though, given the bug that @cHao brought up.  Also, there is the question of whether or not the tab should be called "flag" given that you have flags *and* close votes there now.