# Flagging users that repost after a question has been closed

Tags: discussion, flags

These two questions were both posted by the same user with little modification:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645409/how-to-set-up-levels-like-angry-birds
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644798/how-to-make-a-level-game-in-xcode

There was little to no effort to revise the question, and the OP did not attempt to fix the question after it was closed (for reopening).

I am new to flagging, and I don't want to flood the moderators with flags, but this kind of annoyed me. I've done my best to comment and advise the user on what I found to be lacking in the question.

**If a user creates a nearly exact duplicate of a closed question, should the new question be flagged?**

Comment: This might happen automatically, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94756/flagged-posts-consecutive-closed-questions-what-actions/94758#94758

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Trying to evade the closing of a question by just posting it again is frowned upon and will get the duplicates closed or deleted. A pattern like this certainly flag-worthy behaviour, as a moderator I would want to know it if something like that happens. Though if there is only one duplicate, just closing it and posting a comment that the reposting is not okay might be enough.

Don't be afraid of flagging, just remember, **if you can do anything yourself to solve the problem, like editing a post or voting to close, do that instead of flagging**! If you suspect that you won't manage to get 5 close votes, e.g. if it is an old question you should flag in addition to voting to close. If you can't do anything about it or if it is about a pattern of behaviour from a user you should flag.

In this case the duplicate was already closed by a moderator, so there is no need for more flagging, someone already did it and the moderators are aware.

Comment: Ok, so we're going to go with a 'benefit of the doubt' type policy. I've seen this a few times, so if I notice a pattern with a particular user, maybe then I'll flag.