# Stop showing "consecutive closed questions" flags to 10K users

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, 10k-tools, flags

"consecutive closed questions" is an automatically generated flag that's raised when a user has... consecutive closed questions. The flag can only be actioned by moderators, there's no point in showing it to 10K+ users, as they can't do anything useful with it:

- Closing the question is not an option, the flag appears *after* the question has been closed
- Disagreeing with the flag doesn't make sense
- Flagging to get the flag higher up the queue also doesn't make sense, Community ♦ doesn't have issues with her flag weight.

Related: [Why are “consecutive closed questions” flags exposed to non-moderators?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94756/why-are-consecutive-closed-questions-flags-exposed-to-non-moderators)

Comment: Flagging to get the flag higher also may be detrimental if the flag is dismissed as not helpful. It would hurt weighting of users who are trying to be helpful by trying to push the flag higher if a flag is found to be unnecessary.

Comment: To add to @ThomasOwens point, piggybacking on a Community flag to raise your flag weight *might* provoke a moderator to decline the flag (unless the post really did need immediate moderator attention).

Comment: @BilltheLizard & Yannis - non-mod, 10k+ users don't see who flagged the question; they just see the flag on the question.  So a non-mod wouldn't know that Community flagged the consecutive closed question.

Comment: @GlenH7 That's good to know but irrelevant. The point is that 10K+ users don't help by counterflagging it, regardless of whether their intentions are good (getting it higher up the queue) or bad (what Bill describes).

Comment: @Yannis - agreed in that it's irrelevant to your feature request.  I mostly wanted to clarify what a non-mod can or can't see in order to keep the discussion from veering down an incorrect path.

Comment: There are several autoflags that I ponder what possible action of mine could affect, and this is just one of those.  Others include “too many comments” and “too long” (or whatever the actual text is).  Maybe even “possible vandalism”.  Yes, occasionally autoflags like “possible edit war” can be usefully addressed by a 10k, and perhaps a few others, but some of these are mysteries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

10k users that are not moderators will no longer see the vandalism related flags in their queues.

This will be in the next build.

Answer (score 2):

This is a sample of what a non-mod, 10k+ user sees when a flag comes through.  There's isn't any attribution behind the flagging.

[image]

---

Likewise, there's not a whole lot that a non-mod, 10k+ user can do in the case of this flag.  This image is a sample from a NARQ flag that came through.  For the `consecutive closed question` flag, the option was to flag as VLQ instead of the `invalid flag` shown in the image.

[image]