# No more viewing comment flags?

Tags: support, 10k-tools

I think it's probably just me, but I can't find the link for viewing flagged comments under moderator tools.

Did it leave, or am I just not finding it? (Or was I hallucinating and it never even existed?!)

Comment: They were removed from 10k tools a few month ago. Some info here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93623/feedback-on-tools-flagged-changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mat reports, the possibility to see flagged comments under the 10k tools has been removed when they introduced the possibility for 10k users to see some of the post flags that only moderators were able to see.