# Am I suddenly able to delete comments?

Tags: support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [flagged comments disappear instantly … what's going on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121225/flagged-comments-disappear-instantly-whats-going-on)

I flagged a few of comments as off-topic today, and they disappeared immediately.

Is this coincidental, e.g., enough other people also flagged it and it reached an auto-delete limit?

Or, bless your hearts, have I gotten magical powers?

*Edit* I don't recall all the flags, but indeed, at least one or two were accept-rate-related.

This is nice, but somewhat disappointing as I'd been hoping for [magical powers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145592/168933).

Comment: Questions that are about accept rate, ones that are just "thank you"s and ones that have certain "bad language" in them can be deleted immediately, from what I've seen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What did the comments say?

There are certain phrases that, if found in a flagged comment, cause that comment to be automatically deleted.

They usually concern the posters accept rate.

Comment: Ah. I don't actually recall some of them, but I know at least one of them was an accept-rate-related comment after someone had already embedded an accept-rate nudge inside a larger comment.

Comment: @DaveNewton Here's an [answer from Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99812/who-has-the-power-to-delete-a-comment/99853#99853) where he hints at this functionality.