# Can 10k users still see spam/offensive flags?

Tags: support, 10k-tools, spam, flags, offensive

According to the [privilege page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/66326/15), they can:

> When should I act on spam and offensive flags? [...]

That fact goes back all the way to [revision #1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/66326/1).

But, is this still the case? Personally, I've never seen one, but then again, they're not exactly common.

Recently, I saw [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47023/how-do-you-improve-real-madrids-squad-and-formation-in-fifa-12/47042#47042) in the flag queue with a single "not an answer" flag, but an unusual amount of downvotes (-5), which in my experience is an indicator of spam/offensive flags that carry an automatic downvote.

I'd say it was offensive to *some*, but since it was also completely useless, I decided to flag it as offensive as well, for the sake of bumping it off the site faster.

And, lo and behold, it was destroyed as such at -8, but I never saw an offensive flag on it.

Are normal users able to see spam/offensive flags? If not, since they clearly used to be, why was that ability removed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which flagged posts are visible to 10k users [was changed in June 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93623/feedback-on-tools-flagged-changes). Comment flags, and offensive/spam flags were removed from the 10k view to allow us mere mortals to concentrate on the other ones:

> The trouble was that these [comment/spam] are the easiest flags for us mods to deal with. The trickier ones to deal with are all the rest.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted to know. I'm not sure I agree with that move, though. If someone hadn't flagged it as NAA, I wouldn't have seen the post, and instead of the community taking out the trash, a moderator would have had to step in, possibly hours later. Flag response time isn't exactly stellar on Gaming.

Comment: Maybe you could propose different handling for different sites - I only have 10k rep on Stack Overflow, and over there, spam questions  have a life expectancy of probably 'bout 2min even without being visible in the 10k flags section (which is often over 100 flags deep).

Answer (score 1):

I have seen spam flags, though not in a while.

When they do come up, they tend to get acted on *very* quickly, so the amount of time they are on the flags list is normally very small.