# Who reviews my flags and suggestions?

Tags: discussion, review, flags, faq-proposed

As a mid-rep user, I have a little bit of access to the review tools, and I can infer a little bit about the tools available to higher-rep users from the [Privileges section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), but the information available to me isn't exhaustive.

I'd like to know what subset of users is responsible for reviewing each kind of flag or suggestion I can make on a Stack Exchange site. So that would include:

#### Post Flags:

- *Spam* flags
- *Offensive* flags
- *Duplicate* flags
- *Off-topic* flags
- *Unclear what you're asking* flags
- *Too broad* flags
- *Primarily opinion-based* flags
- *Diamond moderator attention* flags *(okay, so I can probably guess the answer to this one)*

#### Comment flags

- *Rude or offensive* flags
- *Not constructive* flags
- *Obsolete* flags
- *Too chatty* flags
- *Other* flags

#### Other stuff:

- Suggested edits
- Suggestions related to tag wikis (I'm not too familiar with these)
- Anything else I've forgotten

Naturally, at my level of rep I know the answer to *some* of these already, but the majority I'm completely in the dark about. I decided to ask about all of them so that this question will have more value to future readers as a reference question.

Comment: I do know that only diamond moderators handle comment, spam, offensive, and obviously custom flags.

Comment: @Jamal can't 20k also?

Comment: This should be an FAQ entry.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

- **Spam** and **Offensive** can be automatically handled without moderator intervention at six flags, but are only visible to moderators in the flags queue.
- **Recommend Closure** flags (off-topic, unclear, et al) always go to the Close Votes queue (which requires 3k) and are always handled automatically. Moderators do not see them in the flags queue.
- **Custom Moderator Attention** flags can only be seen by moderators and *require* a moderator dismiss them in some way. They cannot be automatically dismissed by a non-moderator action.
- **Comment** flags can only be seen by moderators but can be automatically dismissed if the comment matches a certain auto-deletion phrase or enough users flag it.
- **Not an Answer** flags push the post into the Low Quality Posts queue. They are automatically dismissed if the answer gets deleted at any point, but otherwise require a moderator to dismiss. Most of these flags are handled in the Low Quality Posts queue without moderator intervention.
- **Very Low Quality** flags push the post into the Low Quality Posts queue (which requires 2k) after being active for 15 minutes. They are generally auto-dismissed by community actions.
- **Suggested Edits** on posts can be reviewed by any user who has full editing privileges, through the review queues. The author of the edited post can also unilaterally accept or reject a suggested edit, regardless of their rep.

**Notes:**

- When flags go to the review queues where anyone can take action on them, users are not actually made aware of it being a flag that caused the post to appear there.
- Moderators *can* see flags on their own posts (and comments), but tend to avoid handling them.

Comment: 10kers don't get to see spam/offensive flags.

Comment: Really? I always thought they did. Man, I haven't been a moderator long enough to forget that already.

Comment: Spam / offensive flags once were visible to 10k users, but [that changed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119151/can-10k-users-still-see-spam-offensive-flags), possibly in response to some bad piling-on that used to happen there.

Comment: I am only 3K and I thought that I have reviewed some of the *very low quality* ones?

Comment: @mehow I'm less than 3K, and I have too.

Comment: @mehow Anyone with 2k can "review" a very low quality flag because they go to the Low Quality Flags queue, which only requires 2,000 reputation. Those users cannot actually *view* the flag, though.

Comment: @animuson sorry I am really confused now. What is the difference between reviewing and viewing the flag?

Comment: @mehow In the flags queue, 10k users can see that is is physically marked as "very low quality"and have the ability to flag it as an invalid flag,similar to a not an answer flag, and moderators can see who cast the flag. In the review queue, everyone sees it the same way - an item that needs to be reviewed. They cannot see any actual information about the flag itself (not even a moderator, they'd have to go to the post to see it).

Comment: @animuson Oh that makes sense now. I guess I haven't noticed the difference because I am not 10K+ so I had *nothing(as no other option)* to compare the review process to. Thanks for clarification

Comment: @mehow The difference is fairly subtle, but I felt mentioning them separately was beneficial since they *can* be handled by 10k and/or moderators before they ever make it into the review queue. I've updated the post to clarify a little that they're separate queues/privileges.

Comment: What if I flag a mod's comment, can the mod see it? And can they handle it? I wish you had of left the other Q open, it addresses this specifically

Comment: @Skippy A moderator can see any flag in the system. They can handle them, but avoid doing so because it's in poor taste. Even if the flag is blatantly wrong and has no merit whatsoever, I leave it for another moderator to handle.

Comment: @animuson ok, so when I've complained about this mod, she can see it and it does nothing to assist the harmony on the site whatsoever. I am glad I asked. ty for clarifying cheers

Comment: @Skippy If you want to complain about a moderator, use the "contact us" at the bottom of the site. That goes directly to the SE community team, they are the proper address for complaints about moderators.

Comment: a great and clear answer to a question that crossed my mind just a moment ago (+1 for the question and answer).

Comment: On the sites where I'm a mod we mods avoid handling flags against us because we think it's poor form (conflict of interest).  A moderator on another site told me he sees no problem handling flags against himself (said in the context of dismissing my flag, as I recall).

Comment: Can reviewer see who flagged a question/ answer while reviewing the flagged question / answer?

Comment: @animuson Can you comment on how this changes with the new comment flag types?

Comment: @E.P. The changes to the comment flag reasons don't actually change anything about how they're handled.