# Add a link to the corresponding review queue item to user's flag summary

Tags: feature-request, flags, profile-page, flag-history

Since [some types of flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203217/265907) cause a question/answer to show up in some review queue, I think it would be nice to have a link to the corresponding review queue item in user's flag summary to give them a better insight into how their flag is being handled.

Can we get such a feature?