# What actions in the 10k tools result in flags being dismissed?

Tags: support, 10k-tools, flags

As far as I can make out a single vote to close against a flagged question causes pending VLQ or Close flags to be dismissed as helpful to the flagger. (I inferred this from the "All the flags against this post have been handled now" message you get if you try and flag something after having cast a vote).

Do they really get dismissed from this action? It seems odd that 5 flags might be sufficiently dealt with by a single vote. Do any other actions (edit/delete/vote/comment) also cause flags to be dismissed? Are any other flag types dismissed besides the VLQ and close ones?

(I'm not asking about *"[as soon as a user deals with the flag in any way it will vanish from the list.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93623/153020)"* since whilst that hides it from my list it doesn't dismiss it in any way)

Comment: I'd almost like make this into a feature request: _Don't_ make a single VTC dismiss a flag. The post still needs attention (arguably, it needs _more_ attention, since someone agreed with the flag). But I would guess that was already considered and rejected when they made the flag queue.

Comment: @JacquesCousteau: [They are still visible in the flag-handling tool](http://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged?subtype=close) (link requires appropriate privileges).

Comment: @sarnold: Okay, so other flag handlers will see them, but the raiser of the flag gets a "helpful flag"? Great, that's exactly what I'd want!

Comment: @sarnold I don't think that's the case. See the bit in the question about all the flags have now been handled message.

Comment: @JacquesCousteau Not quite. If the post is flagged *again* afterwards, the dismissed flags will be shown faded alongside the active ones, but other than that the post will disappear from the 10k queue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- **Editing** the post dismisses "very low quality" flags as disputed, since the act of editing contradicts the flagger's statement that the post cannot be salvaged.
- **Casting a close vote** dismisses canned flags (close flags from users with <3k rep and very low quality) on a question as helpful.
- If the post ends up **deleted**, all flags are automatically dismissed as helpful. This can be achieved either by casting the final delete vote or the decisive spam/offensive flag.

Dismissed *for real*, that is. Actions like upvoting/downvoting or flagging only hide the post from your own 10k queue.

Comment: Did not know about edits auto-disputing, it's also the action I was wondering about. It does say *"this question is **unlikely** to be salvageable through editing, and **might** need to be removed"* (emphasis mine)