# I flagged a post as "very low quality" and it was not the last close vote, but it got marked as "none"

Tags: bug, flags, vote-to-close

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13341843/561731) as "very low quality", but the flag got marked as "none"

[image]

There is only one close vote on the question! I thought the "none" to a flag was supposed to kick in on the **last** close vote?

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) maybe?

*Might* be related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155480/155556

Comment: Related: [What actions in the 10k tools result in flags being dismissed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131890/what-actions-in-the-10k-tools-result-in-flags-being-dismissed) This suggests *any* close vote will dismiss a canned flag reason (which include "very low quality"). It says helpful though, but I can't imagine that's still true. It was probably also changed to none.