# How many posts in SO CV queue aren't eligible for vote expiration, ie have no votes, only flags?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close

Is there a way to estimate amount of posts in queue that aren't eligible for vote expiration, that is have [only flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207180/165773)?

I'd like to understand how many posts are guaranteed to eventually leave the queue due to votes being expired and how many are going to stay there for arbitrary long time, [until someone casts a vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131891/165773).

---

For the sake of completeness, it would be interesting to also estimate how many posts in queue have only migration flags, which are [guaranteed to be "aged away"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204347/165773) in 60 days.

Comment: To know how many will leave the queue we'd also need to know how many with votes have enough views for close vote aging

Comment: @RichardTingle I am rather interested to find out how many are guaranteed to stay there irrespectively of aging ("forever", until flag is dismissed by a vote)

Comment: upper estimate for posts eligible for vote expiration is count of questions that are open and have close vote(s). It isn't accurate though, since it contains posts pulled off the queue by _Leave Open_ votes

Comment: @gnat I know this close vote queue size issue troubles you a lot. Maybe you'll find [my question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208220/close-votes-review-im-going-on-a-strike) interesting?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are currently 12,533 review tasks in the close review queue that are there *only* because of flags. If we applied the same aging rules to these flags that we apply to close *votes*, 4,895 of them would age away today.

Of these, 207 are migration flags. For comparison purposes, there are 2285 tasks based on migration *votes*.

In total, 116,958 review tasks have been created in response to flags, and 48,651 such tasks have been completed (the remainder were made ineligible due to deletion, closing from outside the queue, aging, etc.)

---

For Matt: in the past 90 days, 46,506 close flags have been processed; 45,707 were marked as "helpful" (resulted in at least one close vote) and 34,000 have resulted in questions being closed. Note that since more than one flag can be raised for a single post, these numbers do not correspond directly to either *posts* or *review tasks* (that is, they're not directly comparable to the numbers above).

Comment: Have you got any figures on how accurate the flags are? I.e how many of them result in the question actually being closed?

Comment: See edit, @Matt

Comment: Interesting... pretty accurate flagging from the < 3000 rep people.

Comment: I suspect that those people who are most interested in flagging questions for closure are the ones more likely to give a crap about how things work out @Matt. Therefore, they are (probably) more likely to get it right... Anecdotally I don't notice that as much on low quality flags but closure isn't as much of a surprise.

Comment: @Shog9 - In your _Regarding the SOCVQ_ post you mention that there are 11K items left in the queue of the original 57K.  I guess they must all have <100 views.  Can you say how many of those have >1 vote?  (There's so much discussion on this it's hard to find the data.)  I'm thinking of proposing that the <100-view long tail items be closed by default after some time or views, and go in the reopen queue instead, rather than just dropping out after 100 views.