# Why does the SEDE ReviewTaskResults table not include user data, which is all public anyway?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, review, data-explorer, data-dump

I wanted to do [some data mining on the SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281406/can-i-query-the-sede-for-what-fraction-of-close-reviews-are-initiated-by-flags), and I ran across a limitation which I cannot understand.

The Data Explorer table `ReviewTaskResults` [currently contains](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) the following information:

- `Id`
- `ReviewTaskId`
- `ReviewTaskResultTypeId` (listed in `ReviewTaskResultTypes`)
- `CreationDate`
- `RejectionReasonId` (for suggested edits; listed in `ReviewRejectionReasons`)
- `Comment`

However, it does not contain any information on the users casting these reviews. However, **this information is already public**. For recent examples, compare the results at the top of the table with the corresponding review pages on the site, which clearly attribute each review outcome to the corresponding reviewer:

- [Review results with links to the review page](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/513806/review-results-with-links-to-the-review-page)

Is there a privacy reason why this data was cut from the data dumps? It should be relatively straightforward to just include it in future dumps.

Comment: Apart from the [announcement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208806/158100) where Shog9 states to  be over-cautious when leaving out the userid and [one answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208975/158100) to support your scenario I can't find any reason this shouldn't be supported.

Comment: We've taken a very cautious approach to releasing potentially private data. When it comes to SEDE, I'm always a little worried that people will create queries to target specific users for bad behavior. It's one thing to have the data public, but not easily searchable and quite another to have the data collected in one convenient location. That said, I think this is a good candidate for including in the public data and I'll see about adding it.

Comment: @JonEricson Thanks for your response. It's good to know even pretty old requests still have a chance of getting looked at.

Comment: Related on MSO: [How was the number of .015% of Meta users calculated?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387680/how-was-the-number-of-015-of-meta-users-calculated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was answered by Jon Ericson in a comment to this question:

> We've taken a very cautious approach to releasing potentially private data. When it comes to SEDE, I'm always a little worried that people will create queries to target specific users for bad behavior. It's one thing to have the data public, but not easily searchable and quite another to have the data collected in one convenient location. That said, I think this is a good candidate for including in the public data and I'll see about adding it. [Jon Ericson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1438/jon-ericson),  [Dec 8, 2016 at 15:09](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281411/why-does-the-sede-reviewtaskresults-table-not-include-user-data-which-is-all-pu#comment934404_281411)