# Add a ReviewTaskResultTypeId column to the SuggestedEditVotes table in SEDE

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, data-explorer

The Data Explorer's `SuggestedEditVotes` table has a `VoteTypeId` column that can be either 2 or 3 to indicate Approve or Reject, respectively. "Improve Edit" and "Reject and Edit" votes, though, don't appear in that table at all. They do add to `ReviewTaskResults` with an appropriate `ReviewTaskResultTypeId` (5 and 19 are options), but that table has no `UserId` column.

It seems inconsistent to record some Suggested Edits review results in both tables but some in only one. Conveniently, 2 and 3 have the same meaning as a `VoteTypeId` and a `ReviewTaskResultTypeId`, so the missing entries could be added to `SuggestedEditVotes`. Alternatively, add a new `ReviewTaskResultTypeId` column to avoid changing the possible value set of an existing one.

Adding a `UserId` column to `ReviewTaskResults` would also do the job, per [this other request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281411/295684).