# How to flag a question as off topic with current changes?

Tags: support, flags, migration, off-topic

My question is respected to the changes made to the flagging algorithm as reported here on meta [Feedback on tools/flagged changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93623/feedback-on-tools-flagged-changes)

There was question on Stack Overflow -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314020/how-to-differentiate-between-sodium-sulphate-and-potassium-sulphate

The question was subjected to be off topic as it was related to the Chemistry and not coding.
So as a part of flagging i decided to flag the question as off topic but was not able to figure out which option to choose from

[image]

How should i flag the question here ?

When i choose the option as it belongs on other Stack Exchange sites i was having only these options available

[image]

With these options how one can flag the question as off topic ?

**What i have done -**

I choose to flag question as 
[image]

Is it the right way to flag such question ?

**Edit** : Please note that the question has been removed from the SO.

Comment: Seems fine to me. The description could be a bit more..well..descriptive (indicate clearly that you are proposing a migration) but it should be fine.

Comment: There should be an "other" category in the close sub-reasons that allows you to define a custom close reason in a comment. I see it on SO, but there might be some bug with that or some reputation requirement

Comment: @Bart ok will try to add more description while fagging in such case.But yes we are missing the other option here

Comment: @MadScientist yes may be the reputation or bug will be a problem someone also suggested me to use the other option in off topic category but i was not having any such option as shown in the screenshot

Comment: A note (Chemistry moderator here): That would not have been that good a post for Chemistry, it was borderline spam and not that good either.

Comment: Most certainly needed, as we can't simply flag as "off-topic" anymore.  As well, there's a duplicate of Super User on the general off-topic page and the migration page.