# What off-topic flag to use for completely off-topic questions?

Tags: discussion, flags, off-topic

What off-topic flag should I use on SO for a question that has nothing to do with programming, software, and is not suitable for any other SE site?

The reworked flag system confuses me; I don't see any off-topic flag that fits a completely off-topic question.

---

[image]

Comment: It can be flagged as 'need moderator attention->other', see for example [this topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185957/how-to-flag-a-question-as-off-topic-with-current-changes?rq=1)

Comment: Same with MSO off-topic flag options. I can't find a suitable selection for those totally out-of-(m)SE questions.

Comment: The duplicate question doesn't answer my question.

Comment: The linked question *does* answer yours. It says "if one of the pre-written reasons does not fit, you'll have to write your own; use the "Other" reason to enable this."

Comment: @CodyGray I do not see that "Other" reason as shown in the screen shot in that answer.